# Manga or manhwa about a protagonist who ends up with lots of gold and sells it to an influential guy

Tags: story-identification, manga

It was all colour, no monsters at all or use of magic.

Can't remember how it starts, but ends up having lots of gold and sells it to an influential guy in Arabia or something, while saving a girl there trained to be his bodyguard, creating a business and a mercenary group on an island.

The MC may have had abilities but it wasn't like firing off fireballs. He may have been stealing gold and info from an apocalyptic future.