# Manga/manhua involving a character who retrieves gold from a ruined future to sell in the present

Tags: story-identification, manga

Looking for a full color manga or manhua where the main character may have the ability (I can't quite remember) to go to the future, which is destroyed. He steals some gold, then sells it in the modern world. After acquiring a large amount, he sells it to a rich guy in Abu Dhabi or somewhere similar. He then saves a Muslim girl around the age of 16, and trains her to be a bodyguard, while building his own companies led by a silver haired (I think) beautiful assistant and mercenary group. The MC manages to become a private military for this small island nation.

Comment: Are you the same person who posted [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/264535/manga-or-manhwa-about-a-protagonist-who-ends-up-with-lots-of-gold-and-sells-it-t) using a different account, and are you asking about the same manga/manhwa? If so, you should merge the two accounts by following the instructions provided [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts), rather than posting the same question a second time.

Comment: this is litteraly starting point of every manhua had Time travel + post apocalypse

Comment: This could be 我在末世搬金砖 (I Am Carrying Gold From The Post-Apocalyptic World) ,  人在末世，刚成首富 (In a Post-Apocalyptic World, I'll Become the Richest Man Ever!)

Comment: It sounds like Sysphus TV series http://inv.cjr.heroinewarrior.com/entertainment/time-travel-movies-may-2022-netflix-sisyphus

Answer (score 4):

I got you. I am pretty sure you are thinking of *I Have A Mansion In The Post-Apocalyptic World* / *Wo Zai Moshi You Taofang*. This has everything you mentioned, him getting gold from the future, saving a Muslim girl, and building a company using the advanced technology he gets. According to [anilist](https://anilist.co/manga/112261/Wo-Zai-Moshi-You-Taofang):

> Jiang Chen crossed into the judgment day after the nuclear war, and there was a mess everywhere. In order to survive, Jiang Chen led the refugees to establish a base area and set up a federation. Then carry the judgment day's technology and return to the true world. Change the political structure of the earth, rescue the world in a critical moment, and establish the Great Union of Earth Federation! Expanding the territory and fighting the threat from the sky.
>
> [image]

Comment: I don't suppose you can mention whether the gold part is accurate?

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Our 'hero' is capable of moving a cubic metre of stuff between worlds. He settles on gold because the other world is largely abandoned, so collecting it is pretty easy

Comment: The first comment on the question links to another question with a similar premise. Is that one also this manhua?

Comment: Yes, it sounds like it. It is full color. There were technically monsters, but they were more mutants than fantasy creatures. The abilities he has aren't magic either. It is cybernetics, gene enhancement, and technology from traveling to the future.

Comment: :) That would a good thing to [edit] into the answer.